# Python program not responding

Tags: python, tkinter

Have been trying to run my program for several times, the icon and window is there but it's not responding. This actually might have something to do with looping but I'm not sure how to solve this. Is anyone able to help me out with this? Many thanks.

Looping is needed for combobox list.

Here is the code:
No errors found in the shell

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

def CurSelet(evt):
    global sel
    temp=list()
    for i in lbox.curselection():
        temp.append(lbox.get(i))

    allitems=list()
    #for i in range(lbox.size()):
        #allitems.append(lbox.get(i))

    for i in sel:
        if i in allitems:
            if i not in temp:
                sel.remove(i)

    for x in lbox.curselection():
        if lbox.get(x) not in sel:
            sel.append(lbox.get(x))


def update_list():
        
    global sel
    global l
    search_term = search_var.get()

        # Just a generic list to populate the listbox
    lbox_list = Device

    lbox.delete(0, END)

    for item in lbox_list:
        if search_term.lower() in item.lower():
            lbox.insert(END, item)

    allitems=list()


    for i in sel:
        if i in allitems:
            lbox.select_set(lbox.get(0, "end").index(i))


#search box

search_var = StringVar()
search_var.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode: update_list())

searchbox = tk.Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=search_var)
searchbox.place(x = 90, y =60) 

lbox = Combobox(window, width=30, height=4)
lbox.place(x=90,y=90)
lbox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',CurSelet)

update_list()
```

Comment: I even couldn't run your code.It will raise Exception.

Comment: my code has over 500 lines so I have included some parts of it only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add break to this line and stop the looping

```
  for item in lbox_list:
        if search_term.lower() in item.lower():
            lbox.insert(END, item)
            break
```